# How do I create an object with two matrices?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm having some trouble understanding if I'm doing this correctly.

I have to construct an object that contains two 2d matrices. The issue is that I feel I don't properly understand what an object is, so I don't know if my code is correct.

I know for the method `Cfiltering(int numberOfUsers, int numberOfMovies)` I created two more object variables, because it wants two different matrices. Since that method is referring to the `Cfiltering` class object, which creates a `Cfiltering` object and that contains two matrices.

Is this the same as constructing an object that contains two 2d matrices?

This is my first post, so I apologize if I'm not clear in what I'm asking. :)

```
public class Cfiltering {
  private int userMovieMatrix[][];
  private float userUserMatrix[][];

  public Cfiltering() {
    userMovieMatrix = new int[1][1];
    userUserMatrix = new float[1][1];
  }

  /*
   * TODO:COMPLETE THIS I.E. APPROPRIATELY CREATE THE userMovieMatrix AND
   * userUserMatrix WITH CORRECT DIMENSIONS.
   */
  /**
   * Constructs an object which contains two 2d matrices, one of size
   * users*movies which will store integer movie ratings and one of size
   * users*users which will store float similarity scores between pairs of
   * users.
   * 
   * @param numberOfUsers Determines size of matrix variables.
   * @param numberOfMovies Determines size of matrix variables.
   */
  public Cfiltering(int numberOfUsers, int numberOfMovies) {
    // this is a 2d matrix of size users*movies
    userMovieMatrix = new int [numberOfUsers][numberOfMovies];
    // this is a 2d matrix of size users*users
    userUserMatrix = new float [numberOfUsers][numberOfUsers];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick question:
Is this your entire code segment, because if so, you are missing a semicolon.

Two: why are you creating the Cfiltering method twice.  The one at the bottom (the one that looks like a constructor) creates the method to run, so in your main code, just call that method to create a Cfiltering object.

Here is an example of what you would call to run it, but if you want this to be more specialized, please attach your code above.

```
Cfiltering demo = new Cfiltering(7, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods you provided are both called **constructors**. Constructors initialise a new object. This means that after allocating the memory for the object, they make it ready for use. For example, take the following piece of code:

```
Cfiltering foo = new Cfiltering(5,5);
```

This would call upon the second constructor you provided because of the (5,5). That method will indeed create two 2d matrixes inside your object, so yes, that method is correct. You can also call your first method by doing:

```
Cfiltering foo = new Cfiltering();
```

Notice how I left the space between the brackets blank. Because no parameters are provided, Java will execute the method without parameters, which is your first one. That method also creates two matrixes inside the new object.

So yes, you are correct. Both methods create an object that has two matrixes.

Oracle also has some good documentation on this subject, [you can find it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 0):

The method `Cfiltering` of the `Cfiltering` class is called the **constructor** of the class. This method is the first one called and sets up the object after creation. Objects are ***instantiated*** (created) with the **new** keyword.

```
Cfiltering cfiltering1 = new Cfiltering(1, 2);
```

This creates a cfiltering1 object of the class Cfiltering.

```
Cfiltering cfiltering2 = new Cfiltering(2, 4);
```

This also creates a Cfiltering object but with different configuration.

Both objects have two 2D matrixes that are different, not only in the memory, but in length.